# Is there a way to explicitly test if a device supports double-click?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a game, and it allows users to configure their own game settings.

One of the options is to play a card by double-clicking it. However, on a mobile device, if the user selects this option, the game gets stuck because there is no double-click on a mobile device.

So what I'd like to do is detect if a device supports double-click, and if it does, great, but if it doesn't fall back to another preference instead.

I tried this once and failed. I tried detecting if a device supports touch (using modernizr), but that's wrong, because some computers support both double-click and touch, in which case I want to still let people double-click. (supporting touch is not the opposite of supporting double-click)

Is there a  way to tell if a browser/device combo supports a traditional double-click?

Comment: You could try and detect if they're on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

No, outside of prompting the user to attempt to perform the action and detecting if a single or double click occurs, there is not (yet) a cross device standard for detecting available input methods.

You could, on the other hand, attempt to use a detection library like Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/docs/) to detect if you are on a *touch* device, and then swtich from detecting and actual doubleclick to detecting clicks within a frequency. This would look something like the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var lastClick = d.getTime();
var clickDelay = 500; //half second
if(Modernizr.touch){
body.click(function(){
  var currentClick = d.getTime();
  if(currentClick - lastClick < clickDelay){
  lastClick = 0; //prevent tripleclick from registering
  //doubleclick detected, do something
  }
});
} else /*use your current doubleclick detection*/ {
//do something
}
```

I am also oversimplifying, as in this example you would want to be detecting touch events rather than clicks, but this should give the general idea.

Comment: Since there is no good solution, is there a reason to do what you are suggesting vs. just using something like http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/? I get the value of feature detection vs. device detection, but in this case the feature I want to detect isn't directly detectable. Each alternative strikes me as somewhat hackish.

Comment: Well, that's because it is! You are ultimately trying to access system-level hardware information generically through javascript, whcih is pretty explicitly forbidden. Until browsers offer this information programatically and safely we are working around a the indended functionality, the very definition of a hack. To answer your other question, I took my approach because, as you said, what we really want is the feature and not the device. To make the latter work, the impetus would be on you to determine which version of which device on which browser supports the input you are targeting.